# How to create SELECT STATEMENT that will loop and then create the sql statement?

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

I am trying to create a query that will read all rows in table 1 and show them concatenated as if they are one word.

I tried different solutions with no luck.

Imagine a table (CUSTOMER) contains 3 rows (CUST1, CUST2, CUST3)
I want the result of a select statement to give me(CUST1CUST2CUST3) as one row

Notes: I cant use procedures, and if possible the statement should be in PostgreSQL please.

Thanks,

Comment: `SELECT STRING_AGG(customer, '') FROM customer_table`

Answer (score 2):

You can use string_agg function to concat rows in postgresql as follow :

```
SELECT id, string_agg(employee, '')
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I tried this function but it doesn't work on Netezza

Comment: It must work. Can you type your table DDLs, maybe there can be different problem.

Comment: Please review [ask]. Also instead of just saying "it doesn't work",which is totally useless. I can give equally useful reply "well fix it". Neither provides any information the other can use. Instead of "it doesn't work" please provide  [mre]. That way we can provide you a useful response.